# SQL How select most recent records limited by one column

Tags: sql, mysql

There is a MySql database looking like this:

Id / name / hobby / province / created - int8

I want select only three records for every province, but i have no idea how...

So results should be looking like this

[province1]

[1] blah bla

[2] blah blah

[3] blah blah

[province2]

[1] blah bla

[2] blah blah

[3] blah blah

etc.

Thanks for any help.
Best regards.
M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM
(
     SELECT t1.*, @num := IF(@t1 = province,@num+1,1) as num_in_group, @t1 := province
     FROM table_name t1
     INNER JOIN (SELECT @num:=0) num_table
     ORDER BY province ASC, id desc
)xxx WHERE num_in_group <=3
```

This is quite straightforward and not very effective approach, but it might be helpful and good to start with.

**UPDATE**

```
SELECT * FROM
(
     SELECT t1.*, @num := IF(@t1 = province,@num+1,1) as num_in_group, @t1 := province
     FROM table_name t1
     INNER JOIN (SELECT @num:=0) num_table
     INNER JOIN (SELECT @t1 := NULL)x1
     ORDER BY province ASC, id desc
)xxx WHERE num_in_group <=3
```

Comment: First of all - thank You for your help. This script above work well but i have num_table = 1 for all results. But results are nice sorted.

Comment: Can you post the query you are using? I'm pretty sure my query should do the job.

Comment: SELECT * FROM
(
     SELECT t1.*, @num := IF(@t1 = province,@num+1,1) as num_in_group, @t1 := province
     FROM peoples t1
     INNER JOIN (SELECT @num:=0) num_table
     ORDER BY province ASC, id desc
)xxx WHERE num_in_group <=3
- It's working, allmost, num_in_group is equal 1 for every record, but records are well sorted

Comment: I probably misunderstood you. If you don't want extra columns (@t, num_in_group) to be displayed, just list all `province_table` field names in the outer query instead of `SELECT *`.

Comment: Are you sure you have more than 1 record for each province ?

Comment: My query returns no more than 3 records per province (if there is 1 record, it returns 1 record).

Comment: Yeah. I'v got a lot of records, and i get results with no limit. If I good understand in num_in_groupt should be grossing numbers. For first record (province1) - 1, second - 2, third - 3 and no more. But as a result of your query I'v got all records (with no limit) and in num_in_group columnt every record is equal 1

Comment: @Pablo: Did you copy the `order by province` to your query?  It's essential that the records are ordered by province, or `num_in_group` will reset after most rows

Comment: I found the problem. Check the modified version. In the original version I forgot to add `INNER JOIN (SELECT @t1 := NULL)x1` which caused the query show wrong results first time (all consecutive call within the same session returned the proper results). Updated version should not have this problem.

Comment: You are the gratest :) Work's like a charm. Thank You very much.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it can be done by one query, unless your database is small and so you can do further filtering in script.

- first, find out what provinces you have: SELECT DISTINCT province FROM t
- run a separate query for each of the provinces, sorting it by 'created DESC' and LIMIT 3.
- make sure 'province' and 'created' are indexed.

Comment: Doing queries in a loop is always a bad solution.

Answer (score 1):

The "top N per group" problem is easy in databases that support `row_number()`, but MySQL is not one of those.  There are as far as I know only fairly ugly workarounds.  One approach is the `group_concat` way:

```
select  yt.province
,       lst.value
,       substring_index(
            substring_index(
                group_concat(name separator ';'),
                ';',lst.value),
            ';',-1)
from    YourTable yt
cross join
        (
        select 1 as value
        union all select 2
        union all select 3
        ) lst
group by
    yt.Province
,       lst.value;
```

This will return duplicate rows if there's less than three names per province.  You could exclude those with another subquery.

Another approach is the variable way, as posted by Alex (which I voted for).  In a slightly different format:

```
select  *
from    (
        SELECT  name
        ,       province
        ,       @num := if(@lastprov = province,@num+1,1) as num_in_group
        ,       @lastprov := province
        from    YourTable yt
        order by
                province
        ) as SubQueryAlias
JOIN    (SELECT @num:=0, @lastprov:=null) as DeclareVariablesSubquery
WHERE   num_in_group <= 3;
```

Test data:

```
drop table if exists YourTable;

create table YourTable (id int, name varchar(25), province varchar(25));
insert YourTable values 
    (1,'Barack','New York'), 
    (2,'George W','New York'),
    (3,'William','New York'),
    (4,'George HW','New York'),
    (5,'Ronald','Texas'),
    (6,'James','Texas'),
    (7,'Gerald','Texas'),
    (8,'Richard','Texas'),
    (9,'Lyndon','California'),
    (10,'John','California'),
    (11,'Dwight','Rhode Island'),
    (12,'Harry','Wisconsin');
```

Comment: Thanks for vote. There was a problem in my original query, so you probably need to change your second approach slightly as well (I missed @lastprov initialization that caused wrong results when the query executed for the fist time).

Answer (score 0):

This won't work for MySQL (which is why I marked this answer as community wiki), but it's interesting for people using a different DBMS and stumbling upon this question :

```
WITH TT (id, province, R) AS (
    SELECT id, province, row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY province ORDER BY id DESC)
      FROM your_table
  GROUP BY id, province
)
SELECT id, province
  FROM TT
 WHERE R <= 3;
```